# Change letter case of column names

Tags: r

I have a large number of data sets each containing a long list of column names.  In some files the column names are all capital letters and in some files only the first letter of the column names is capitalized.  I need to append the data sets and thought the easiest way to match column names among data sets would be to convert the all-capital names into names with only the first letter capitalized.

I am hoping to find a general solution, maybe even a one-liner.

Here is my example data set.  The desired names are included in the `names` statements.

```
my.data2 <-  "
landuse units grade CLAY    LINCOLN  BASINANDRANGE  MCCARTNEY  MAPLE
apple   acres AAA     0         2          3             4         6
apple   acres AA   1000       900         NA            NA       700
pear    acres AA   10.0        20         NA          30.0        40
peach   acres AAA   500       400        350           300       200
"
my.data2 <- read.table(textConnection(my.data2), header=TRUE)

names(my.data2)[names(my.data2)=="CLAY"]            <- "Clay"
names(my.data2)[names(my.data2)=="BASINANDRANGE"]   <- "BasinandRange"
names(my.data2)[names(my.data2)=="LINCOLN"]         <- "Lincoln"
names(my.data2)[names(my.data2)=="MCCARTNEY"]       <- "McCartney"
names(my.data2)[names(my.data2)=="MAPLE"]           <- "Maple"

my.data2
```

Note that I included the names `McCartney` and `BasinandRange` to make things more realistic and more difficult.  However, if I can find a one-liner to deal with 95% of the names and use the above `names` statements to deal with complications like `McCartney` and `BasinandRange` that would be great.

I have searched the internet, including the StackOverflow archives, without finding a solution.  Sorry if I overlooked one.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you converted all the names to all-uppercase or all-lowercase using `toupper` or `tolower`, respectively.  Converting them to mixed case will be harder.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is a one-liner implementing "the easiest way to match column names among data sets" that I can think of:

```
## Columns 1:3 left unaltered since they are not place names.
names(my.data2)[-1:-3] <- tolower(names(my.data2)[-1:-3])

## View the results
names(my.data2)
# [1] "landuse"       "units"         "grade"         "clay"         
# [5] "lincoln"       "basinandrange" "mccartney"     "maple"
```

Comment: would you know how to assign lowercase labels back to the variables e.g. `tolower(Hmisc::label(df))` converts the labels to lower case but I'm not sure how to assign them back to the dataset?

Comment: figured it out, it might be of some help to someone, `a <- tolower(Hmisc::label(df))` then `Hmisc::label(df) = as.list(a[match(names(df), names(a))])`

Answer (score 28):

Easy Solution

`names(DF) <- toupper(names(DF))`

Answer (score 26):

## modern solution

This is now a job for `janitor::clean_names()`, just choose `case` parameter that fits you need.

Comment: I tried clean_names, but it inserts underscores in my column names.  Other people have reported this, but only for non-standard characters.  In my case, they were mostly standard letters.  eg, converting SPMu_xyz produced sp_mu_xyz for all instances where an underscore was present elsewhere in the column name.

Answer (score 18):

Combining two of the answers here, I've come up with an elegant `tidy` way:

This renames all column/variable names by capitalising the first letter of every word.

```
library(tidyverse)

my.data2 %>%
  rename_with(str_to_title)
```

Comment: anyway to do this across multiple columns using something like the across function?

Comment: @tnt I think that this snippet already does that: `rename_with` here applies `str_to_title` to every column in `my.data2`. If you mean something else by "across multiple columns," could you give an example to clarify?

Comment: The issue is, it leaves the underscore. Again we need to write something to remove underscore

Answer (score 11):

data.table syntax, I believe would save more time and efficient. its also a one line statement, even shorter.

```
library(data.table)
setnames(my.data2, tolower(names(my.data2[4:8])))

#   landuse units grade clay lincoln basinandrange mccartney maple
#1:   apple acres   AAA    0       2             3         4     6
#2:   apple acres    AA 1000     900            NA        NA   700
#3:    pear acres    AA   10      20            NA        30    40
#4:   peach acres   AAA  500     400           350       300   200
```

**Update 2023** 
Your question was to capitalise the first letter which we didn't quite address then. Here is an updated one-liner `data.table` approach.

```
setnames(my.data2, 4:8, tools::toTitleCase(names(my.data2)[4:8]))
```

Answer (score 8):

A "tidy" solution:

```
library(dplyr)

my.data2.mod <- my.data2 %>% 
  rename_at(c("CLAY", "LINCOLN", "BASINANDRANGE", "MCCARTNEY",  "MAPLE"),
            .funs = tolower)

names(my.data2.mod) 
# [1] "landuse"       "units"         "grade"         "clay"         
# [5] "lincoln"       "basinandrange" "mccartney"     "maple"
```

Also, to answer the original question and leave some cases capitalized, you can use the `snakecase` package:

```
library(snakecase)

my.data2.mod = my.data2 %>% 
  rename_at(
    c("CLAY", "LINCOLN", "BASINANDRANGE", "MCCARTNEY",  "MAPLE"),
    .funs = list(
      ~ to_upper_camel_case(., 
                            abbreviations = c("McCartney", "BasinandRange")
                            )
      )
    )

names(my.data2.mod)
# [1] "landuse"       "units"         "grade"         "Clay"         
# [5] "Lincoln"       "BasinandRange" "McCartney"     "Maple"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
colnames(df) <- stringr::str_to_title(colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

I used Josh O'Brien's answer, but eventually wrote the code below that creates column names with the first letter
in upper case and the other letters in lower case, with a few exceptions handled as in the original post.  Below I used the same data set as in the original post, but read that data into R differently where `n.col` determines the number of columns in the data file:

```
n.col <- as.numeric(length(scan("c:/users/mark w miller/simple R programs/names_with_capital_letters.txt", 
         what="character", nlines=1)))

my.data2 <- read.table(file = "c:/users/mark w miller/simple R programs/names_with_capital_letters.txt", 
            na.string=NA, header = T, colClasses = c('character', 'character', 'character', 
            rep('numeric', (n.col[1] - 3))))

first.letter  <- substring(names(my.data2)[-1:-3], 1, 1)
other.letters <- tolower(substring(names(my.data2)[-1:-3], 2))
newnames      <- paste(first.letter, other.letters, sep="")

names(my.data2)[-1:-3] <- newnames
names(my.data2)[names(my.data2)=="Basinandrange"]   <- "BasinandRange"
names(my.data2)[names(my.data2)=="Mccartney"]       <- "McCartney"

my.data2

#   landuse units grade Clay Lincoln BasinandRange McCartney Maple
# 1   apple acres   AAA    0       2             3         4     6
# 2   apple acres    AA 1000     900            NA        NA   700
# 3    pear acres    AA   10      20            NA        30    40
# 4   peach acres   AAA  500     400           350       300   200
```

Answer (score 2):

This will make every column upper case.

```
rename_with(names,toupper)
```

Comment: rename_with isn't base R.

Answer (score 0):

A recent 'tidy' solution I arrived at which renames all columns by making the first letter uppercase and doing nothing to the rest of the string.

Preliminaries:

```
library(tibble)  
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

    
df <- tibble("column 1" = rep(1,10),
             "column 2 ABC" = rep("a",10),
             "Column 3 Abc" = rep("b", 10))
head(df)

  `column 1` `column 2 ABC` `Column 3 Abc`
       <dbl> <chr>          <chr>         
1          1 a              b             
2          1 a              b             
3          1 a              b             
4          1 a              b             
5          1 a              b             
6          1 a              b
```

Rename columns using custom function:

```
df <- df %>%
    rename_with(function(x) str_replace(x, "^.", toupper))
    
head(df)

  `Column 1` `Column 2 ABC` `Column 3 Abc`
       <dbl> <chr>          <chr>         
1          1 a              b             
2          1 a              b             
3          1 a              b             
4          1 a              b             
5          1 a              b             
6          1 a              b
```

The regex "^." can be understood as (based on https://regexr.com/7rp4k):

- "^": beginning of the string
- ".": matches any character