# What is the most efficient way to change the case of column names in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata

Sometimes before merging it's useful to change the case of the column names for consistency. When working with a `data.frame` this is pretty straightforward (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258020/change-letter-case-of-column-names)); although the same solution works on ``data.table`, it throws a warning. For example,

```
ran <- rep(34,50)
dom <- rep("cat",50)
table <- rep("pig", 50)

DT <- data.table(ran,dom,table); head(DT)
   ran dom table
1:  34 cat   pig
2:  34 cat   pig
3:  34 cat   pig
4:  34 cat   pig
5:  34 cat   pig
6:  34 cat   pig

##the data.frame way

names(DT) <- toupper(names(DT))

##the error 
Warning message:
In `names<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, value = c("RAN", "DOM", "TABLE" :
  The names(x)<-value syntax copies the whole table. This is due to <- in R 
 itself. Please change to setnames(x,old,new) which does not copy and is faster. 
 See help('setnames'). You can safely ignore this warning if it is inconvenient 
 to change right now. Setting options(warn=2) turns this warning into an error, 
 so you can then use traceback() to find and change your names<- calls.
```

I've used the following workaround to avoid the error, and it's much faster on wide datasets, but is there a `data.table` way to do this?

```
##the work around
upper <- toupper(names(DT))

setnames(DT,upper);head(DT)

   RAN DOM TABLE
1:  34 cat   pig
2:  34 cat   pig
3:  34 cat   pig
4:  34 cat   pig
5:  34 cat   pig
6:  34 cat   pig
```

Comment: `setnames` is a function from the `data.table` package, and as the warning states this is the preferred way of doing things.

Comment: So are you asking for anything more than compacting your workaround to something like `setnames(DT,toupper(names(DT)))` ?

Comment: I don't know if you edited your question...anyways, as the previous comments already said, `setnames` is **not** a work around, as you phrase it, but the `data.table` way to do it. So you can just post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Just to make this clear, a warning message in R is NOT an error unless you explicitly promote it to an error in `options()` [usually for debugging purposes], as the helpful warning message noted. Had you checked `str(DT)` after your `toupper()` call, you would have found that `DT` existed - it would not have had an error been thrown from the `toupper()` call.

Comment: thanks for the responses. I just wanted to know if there was a more appropriate syntax for passing the operation to ``data.table`` than what I did, which @Matthew has answered. As mentioned in my post, you can use the same syntax as you would on a ``data.frame`` and though it throws a warning message it still works. I guess 'error' was the wrong word choice so sorry for the confusion there. It seems my 'work around' was actually the appropriate way to do it, which is what I wanted to know. For the record even though the ``data.frame`` way works the ``data.table`` way is much much faster.

Comment: @kpeyton. Nice to hear. In fact `setnames` should be (almost) infinitely faster, since even for very large tables it should take (almost) a constant 0.00 seconds. The `data.frame` way copies the entire table, just to change the names. Even a single copy can be quite significant and may even mean you get the dreaded 'out of memory' error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give this an answer, as the comments say, `setnames` is a `data.table` function and is already the `data.table` recommended way (as that long warning from `data.table` suggests); e.g.,

```
setnames(DT,toupper(names(DT)))
```

Not to be confused with the `setNames` function from the `stats` package! (Note the upper case `N`).